# How does commonjs require("moduleName") work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I have had a stupid question on my mind for a while:
How does `require("moduleName")` work?

I understand that if I have a file `moduleA.js` in my project, I could load the module using `require("./moduleA")`. But for many "well-known libraries" such as express, lodash, etc, I don't need to explicitly write the relative path in which the is library located.  Instead I just use the module name (e.g. `require('lodash');`). My question is: how does that work? How can I make my own module work in that way, where the module can be loaded globally without writing the path(e.g. `require('moduleA')`).

Thanks

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/mathisonian/c325dbe02ea4d6880c4e, https://github.com/feross/buffer

Comment: This is a pretty loaded question, RisingStack Engineer has a [good blog post on this](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/) that has a good amount of detail on how the Module System in Node (CommonJS) works.

Answer (score 1):

When you install a library with NPM, the library get installed in a folder called `node_modules` and when you make the `require` keyword, node look for the package name in that folder.
When you require for a js file, you should specify its path.

Answer (score 1):

A relative path like `require('./moduleA')` means you're importing a script or module within your project. A "well-known" path like `require('loadash')` means you're importing an external dependency, which may be installed locally to your project under `C:/path/to/project/node_modules/lodash` or globally to your account or computer, depending on how you configured `npm` when you installed Node.js. That path may be something like `C:/Users/yourname/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/lodash` for example.

If you publish your module on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/), others will be able to install it as an external dependency and `require()` it without having to specify a relative path to it.